# Laravel 5.4 Served in subdirectory Nginx. 404 when including js files

Tags: javascript, laravel, nginx, http-status-code-404, subdirectory

My problem is serving CSS and JS files using Laravel 5.4 on an Nginx server (Ubuntu). I have configured the server to serve the application from a nested sub-directory (not in the root of the web server). Routing is working. See:

- https://zwestwind.com/sandboxes/zypth/blog/tasks
- https://zwestwind.com/sandboxes/zypth/blog/posts
- and just ..blog/ as well.

The problem is that I cannot include JS files (and likely css). The JS file is in "blog/public/js/posts.js".

Attached below is my site configuration, and the code to include a JS file in a blade template. You can view the error in the console when you hit the site.

Server Configuration:

```
server {
    return 404;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www/zwestwind.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    #server_name example.com www.example.com;
    server_name zwestwind.com www.zwestwind.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/pub_clf_origin.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/priv_clf_origin.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    # route to laravel project: $uri = /sandboxes/zypth/blog/public/index.php
    location ~ ^/sandboxes/zypth/blog {
        alias /var/www/zwestwind.com/html/sandboxes/zypth/blog/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @laravel;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            #fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/zwestwind.com/html/sandboxes/zypth/blog/public/index.php;
        }
    }

    location @laravel{
        rewrite /sandboxes/zypth/blog/(.*)$ /sandboxes/zypth/blog/index.php?/$1 last;
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        # With php5-cgi alone:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

Blade code to include the JS file:

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('posts.js', true) }}"></script>
```

Things that I have tried:

- I have tried using 'js/posts.js' and many other variations, including hardcoded paths such as 'zwestwind.com/sandboxes/zypth/blog/public/posts.js' to no avail (with the protocol, I can only post 2 links due to reputation).
- Adding a location block: location ~ .js$ {...} to add a content-header of application/x-javascript
- I have configured a vhost server to serve the same application at (http)blog.zwestind.com/posts. All routing and inclusion of CSS/JS files works there, check it out. The server config for that sub domain is exactly as specified in the Laravel installation guide.

I am guessing this issue stems from a server config problem with the primary domain... ie) the location block listening for "^/sandboxes/zypth/blog" is catching the request for the JS file and modifying the URI, thus resulting in a 404. How would I fix this?

When the script works, it will say "posts.js is ready!" in the console (see the sub domain on http for an example).

Thanks.

P.S. If anyone is curious as to WHY I want to serve this app (and more) in a nested directory, it is because I want to host live demo apps using ONE SSL cert via ONE domain while also learning how to configure web servers. This server is not intended for heavy traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the file like this:

```
<script src="/js/posts.js"></script>
```

The  "/" before the directory sends the request to the root (public folder), where the js and css directories are.

I found this better then adding new location root or aliases in the nginx config.

I do the same with images and it works fine.